# Cant search for specific results in ajax

Tags: php, arrays, json

So I cannot search for specific results on my code, but the webservice shows all the results when i click search button. For example when i type in london on the region form field it wont come up with london it will instead load every result in the database. The results are not specific to what i search and i am confused since i feel like it is correct. If i want a specific result that specific result wont load. I have also shown my code, can anyone figure out what is wrong>

```
                        window.onload = function() {



      init();
     };

                      function init() {

                 document.querySelector("#Submit").addEventListener("click", 
       sendAjax);
    console.log("function init is running");
 };

function sendAjax() {

  var region = document.querySelector("#region").value;
  var type = document.querySelector("#type").value;   
console.log("type is: " + type);
console.log("region is: " + region);



  var ajaxConnection = new XMLHttpRequest();
   console.log("ajaxConnection is: " + ajaxConnection);


  ajaxConnection.addEventListener("load", e=>{
  console.log("AJAX connected.");

  var output = "";
  var poiResults = JSON.parse(e.target.responseText);

  //Loop through each.
  poiResults.forEach (poiResponse=>{
      //Results of the query output in variable "output".
      output = output + `<br>
                         Name: ${poiResponse.name} <br>
                         Type: ${poiResponse.type} <br>
                         Country: ${poiResponse.country} <br>
                         Region: ${poiResponse.region} 
                         Longtitude: ${poiResponse.Longtitude}
                         Lattitude: ${poiResponse.Lattitude}
                         Description: ${poiResponse.description}<br><br>`;
  });

         //Output in div with ID of "response".
         var response = document.querySelector("#response");
       response.innerHTML = output;
      });

   //Open the connection to a remote URL.
  //Use backticks for easier variable integration.
  ajaxConnection.open("GET", 
`https://user.user.ac.uk/~user/webservice.php? 
 type=${type}&Region=${region}`);

  //Send the request.
 ajaxConnection.send();
 };
```

here is the html

```
     <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <title>POI test</title>
</head>
       <body>
 <article role="article">
   <section>
   <h1>HT Tracks</h1>
  <input type="text" name="region" id="region" placeholder="region">
     <input type="text" name="type"  id="type" placeholder="Type">

  <input type="button" id="Submit" value="Submit">
   <div id="response"></div>
     </section>
       </article>

        </body>
           </html>

    And here is my webservice 

       <?php


        header("Content-type: application/json");


      $region= $_GET["region"];
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user;", 
   "user","user");
 $results = $conn->query("SELECT*FROM pointsofinterest 
                     WHERE region LIKE '%$r%' AND type LIKE '%$t%'");

 $resultsAsAssocArray = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 echo json_encode($resultsAsAssocArray) ;


  ?>
```

Comment: In your SQL query, you aren't passing anything that would change the response. I assume you want your $region variable to have impact on the SQL query? If that is the case, you need to parameterize it into your SQL query. I can post an answer if you think this is what you'll want

Comment: Hi can you explain with an answer?

Comment: Yeah, give me about 15 minutes

Comment: alright, it's there

Answer (score 0):

So without seeing your DB schema or much else, I can't tell you exactly how to format your PHP code/SQL query, but it would look something like the following (it would help if you posted your DB schema, too :)):

```
$region= $_GET["region"];
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user;","user","user");
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM pointsofinterest WHERE region=?");
$results = $stmt->execute([$region]);

$resultsAsAssocArray = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($resultsAsAssocArray);
```

What you're doing here is parameterizing your query. To prevent SQL injection, you're putting a placeholder in your query (the ?) to prevent the potentially unsafe data in $_GET['region'] from being automatically passed into your SQL query and creating a SQL injection vulnerability. PDO then "prepares" the statement, and replaces the '?' with what you passed (as an array) in the execute() function call (in this case, we passed the $region variable).

That SQL may not work for you though, because I don't know what is in that 'region' column, I can only guess on context. If you post your complete schema, I can give you a more robust answer.